# How to change the standard event handler signature of asp Updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, error-handling, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I always used to use standard **Asp.net** Controls beside **AjaxControlToolkit** and never faced a problem. Recently I had to use **Dundas Charting** controls which are not standard .NET controls and I have to control a part of apage based on the report shown in **Dundas**.

Unfortunately Dundas Event Signature does not recognized by UpdatePanel and Iget the following error

**Description:**

```
 An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

**Exception Details:**

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: The 'CommandFired' event on associated control 'chart1' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'updatepanel1' does not match the standard event handler signature.
```

So I want to know that is there any possibility to change the Handler signature of updatepanel? If yes, How to do that?

Comment: IMO, what is event signature like? Standard event signature means `void` return type and two arguments - `object`(sender) and event arguments (of type derived from 'EventArgs`). I feel it's unlikely that Dundas would have different signature - perhaps problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the `CommandFiredEventArgs` class does not derive from `System.EventArgs` which is probably the issue. Rather than try and change the signature that the UpdatePanel is expecting, I would derive a subclass from the Chart object and then add your own events, with your own EventArgs class as part of the signature. It should then be easy to hook these up to the existing Dundas events.

A very rough sample without access to VisualStudio below. This has not been compiled so please tidy it up yourself, but it outlines the general idea.

```
public class CustomChart : Dundas.Charting.WebControl.Chart
{
     public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyCustomEvent;

     public CustomChart()
     {
          this.CommandFired += SomeMethod;
     }

     private void SomeMethod(object sender, CommandFiredEventHandler args)
     {
          this.OnMyCustomEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
     }

     protected void OnMyCustomEvent(EventArgs args)
     {
         if (this.MyCustomEvent != null)
         {
              this.MyCustomEvent(this, args);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Good hint mate, but 'CommandFiredEventArgs' is sealded by dundas

Comment: I'm not suggesting you derive from the Dundas event args. You'll need to create a new EventArgs class yourself, derived from System.EventArgs and add into it whatever you need from the Dundas one. You'll then need to map from the Dundas CommandFiredEventArgs to the CustomCommandFiredEventArgs when you fire your custom event. Obviously, if you don't need any information, you can just make the signature (object, EventArgs) and fire the event using EventArgs.Empty.

Comment: No problem, let us know how you get on.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't put your advice in practice, so my problem still exist, Can you update your answer with a sample code?